# Data binding library with support for generics and SWT/JFace?

Tags: java, data-binding, swt, jgoodies

JFace Databinding doesn't support generics, so it isn't particularly type-safe. And apparently it never will, since they wish to preserve Java 1.3 support.

JGoodies supports generics since 2.0.0. Has anyone ported JGoodies 2 to SWT/JFace? Or is there another library which allows both?

Comment: On a related issue: I recently needed a version of org.eclipse.core.databinding.property and .observable with generics, so I added them. Available there: https://github.com/jppellet/org.eclipse.core.databinding.property and https://github.com/jppellet/org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable

Answer (score 2):

> JFace Databinding doesn't support generics, so it isn't particularly type-safe. And apparently it never will, since they wish to preserve Java 1.3 support.

Just want to provide clarification.  Going forward we are targeting Java 5 and planning to retool the API to use generics.

[Stay tuned](http://fire-change-event.blogspot.com/).

-- Matthew (project committer)

Comment: Any chance of this happening?

Comment: Unfortunately my work on Eclipse databinding has fallen by the wayside. At this time I can't say when or even if I'll get actively involved again.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the JFace binding framework is typeless, which is why I don't use it.

Let's say 'person' is a pojo with a getName() method.

```
bindingContext.bindValue(SWTObservables.observeText(name, SWT.Modify), PojoObservables.observeValue(person, "name"));
```

If you change the getName() method, to getEntireName(), the compiler will not catch anything for you - you'll get a runtime exception.

I use a controller between my model and JFace and deal with it that way.  I'm not willing to give up the typing.

Comment: What you've observed is a weakness of the JavaBeans specification itself.  POJOs and JavaBeans will suffer from this refactoring issue until Java introduces real property support.  Which may never happen.